# Avoid vim removes indentation when a word starts with a colon

Tags: vim

When I want to write

```
{
    var myJson = {
        property:"value"
    }
}
```

in vim, the second line jumps to the beginning of the line when I type the `:`.
How can I avoid that?

I have this problem while editing *.js files, not for instance in *,vb files (in which it would make sense).

Comment: so, you mean, **not** "when a word starts with a colon".

Comment: That's surprising, the usual vim smartindent for .js files doesn't do that.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a wrong `indentexpr`. For me `cindent` and `smartindent` are both set **and** `cinkeys`/`indentkeys` includes `:` for js files, but I don't get the behaviour described.

Check

```
:verbose set ft? cinkeys? indentkeys? cindent? smartindent? indentexpr?
```

to find out which (filetype) plugin causes these settings

Comment: `cindent` was already set and I just set `smartindent`. `cinkeys` and `indentkeys` include `:` and `indentexpr` is blank. I still have the problem.

Comment: long shot: what does `:verbose imap :` say

Comment: `! <S-Insert>   <C-R><C-D>*`  `i <C-U>     * <C-G>u<C-U>`

Comment: Hmm. That looks odd. Most interestingly, what script was it last set from? Try disabling that script

Comment: When I comment everything out in `{vim path}\indent\javascript.vim` the problem is gone, but automatic indentation is gone too. When I then manually `set cindent` it reoccurs.

Comment: @DirkHorsten you can look here - http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html#cinoptions-values (No recommendations on how to deal with that filetype indent file...)

Comment: thanks: I now have a work around: inserting a blank before my colon `property :"value"`